# Verify unique data from either/or and join. Using R to make a booklist

Tags: r

I am trying to modify an R function which currently makes sure ISBNs are unique in Zotero data to check for ISBNs *or* DOI's.
I found this great package for creating a booklist in Google sheets from a Zotero group and I want to use it to build a simple sheet to track my dissertation reading (see: https://github.com/joelnitta/booklist). I have been able to successfully modify it to suit the data I want to retrieve *however* much of my material uses DOIs rather than ISBNs. I can get a DOI function working, similar to the existing ISBN but I can't figure out how to get it to look for *either* an ISBN or DOI, check for uniqueness, return the appropriate error messages, and later during the update phase join on unique ISBNs *or* DOIs. Any help is appreciated!

I am using RStudio v1.2.1335 on a Macbook Pro OSv10.14.6 (Mojave). I have been searching for an answer and have tried several versions of syntax but have yet to be successful. I can only get either unique DOI or unique ISBN, but not both.

```
#' Verify that all ISBN numbers are unique
#'
#' @param data Dataframe including at least one column called "isbn"
#' @param data_source Either "Google" or "Zotero"
#'
#' @return TRUE if there are no duplicate ISBN numbers or an error stating
#' which ISBN numbers are duplicates.
check_isbn <- function(data, data_source = c("Google", "Zotero")) {

  assertthat::assert_that(!any(is.na(data$isbn)),
                          msg = "One or more ISBNs are missing")

  assertthat::assert_that(!any(data$isbn == ""),
                          msg = "One or more ISBNs are missing")

  dup_isbn <-
    data %>%
    dplyr::count(isbn) %>%
    dplyr::filter(n > 1) %>%
    dplyr::pull(isbn) %>%
    paste(collapse = ", ")

  assertthat::assert_that(
    dup_isbn == "",
    msg = glue::glue("Duplicate ISBNs detected in {data_source} data: {dup_isbn}.
                     Please remove these before updating.")
    )
}


#' Update Sheet: Synchronize a Zotero bibliography and a Google Sheet
#'
#' It is assumed that the Google Sheet is located in the root folder of the
#' user's Google Drive.
#'
#' @param groupID ID number of Zotero group with bibliography
#' @param api_key API key needed to access Zotero group
#' @param sheet_name Name of the Google Sheet
#'
#' @return A \code{\link[googlesheets]{googlesheets}} object;
#' the Google Sheet should be updated with new book entries from Zotero, if any.
#' @export
update_booklistannotated <- function (groupID, api_key, sheet_name) {

  # Read in current bibliographic data from Zotero
  zotero_data <- get_zotero(groupID = groupID,
                            api_key = api_key)

  # Make sure ISBNs are unique in Zotero data
  check_isbn(zotero_data, "Zotero")

  # Get book status data (whether purchased or checked out) from Google Sheets
  book_status <- load_gs_data(sheet_name) %>%
    dplyr::select(isbn, contains("purchased"), contains("checked_out"))

  # Make sure ISBNs are unique in Google data
  check_isbn(book_status, "Google")

  # Merge Zotero data with book status and update Google Sheet
  book_update <-
    dplyr::full_join(zotero_data, book_status) %>%
    dplyr::mutate_all(~ifelse(is.na(.), "", .))

  # Update Google Sheet with new data
  googlesheets::gs_title(sheet_name) %>%
    googlesheets::gs_edit_cells(input = book_update)

}
```